# Microsoft Graph api - write files to my oneDrive

Tags: javascript, azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am writing a simple web app (Javascript) that includes a form, once the form has been submitted I want to save the data on my oneDrive as a new file. That's all! But for some reason, I cannot accomplish this simple task.

So I want to use oneDrive as my database. but all I can find on the Microsoft Graph API are require a login popup which does not make sense here for me in this case cause the user have nothing to do with that. just want the details will be submitted into my personal oneDrive.

I am using client_credentials flow to generate access token but I keep getting errors like 'Unable to retrieve tenant service info.' or 'Current authenticated context is not valid for this request'
when I try to access the drive API.
I gave all the possible permissions to this app, I am using my personal free Microsoft account

so What am I missing here?

Another issue that I will be happy to know more about is that in my Azure app registration after I register this app and I go to the owner's tab I see this message - 'This app does not belong to any directory, so owners can’t be added to it.' is that might be the problem? how and do I even need to assign this app to a certain directory to use the API for my personal drive?

Also when I am vising the Users section on my Azure portal I see this message - 'You don't have access to this data.'
How is that possible if I do not belong to any organization and I created this azure account??

Thank you in advance, any information here will be helpful cause I am kinda lost.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using client_credentials flow to generate access token but I keep
> getting errors like 'Unable to retrieve tenant service info.' or
> 'Current authenticated context is not valid for this request' when I
> try to access the drive API.

For this you could use the Code Flow authentication

[image]

In this, you will not be needing any tenant information - just the client credentials and access token to access the OneDrive API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#code-flow

> This app does not belong to any directory, so owners can’t be added to
> it

If the app **had been** registered in the converged app portal - you are likely to encounter this. You can you portal access this [link](https://aka.ms/AppRegistrations/?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.onedrive.com) and login with your personal account\live account.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attempt to help, but I'm still getting errors here. It's neither 'Proof Key' problem which has zero info about on the docs. Or that i am still prompt to login, which is exactly what i am trying to avoid here.